# Plotting XY on ArcMAP from csv file using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, csv

I have a .csv file with XY coordinates that can be converted to a .dbf file and loaded in ArcMAP. How do I plot the coordinates in that file in ArcMAP using arcpy.

Without arcpy, we could right click the loaded .dbf from table of contents and click "Display XY Data".

Answer (score 3):

You will need to make an XY Event layer and use the appropriate parameters for input fields. Here is the help doc that shows the syntax to be used.
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm